# Google map center (lat/lng) issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The script that I use for google map in my site is

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>`

I get the center from a hidden input by

`var pos = $('#lat_lng').val();`

in my console it `pos` print as`23.810332,90.41251809999994`

The problem is if I use 
`var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(pos);` google map doesnot work but if I use

`var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(23.810332,90.41251809999994);`

It works fine. Where is the main problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main problem is that this  `new google.maps.LatLng` take 2 parameters from the type double so when you pass `Pos` you pass one parameter from type `string` 
but when pass `23.810332,90.41251809999994` you pass two parameters from type  `double`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct constructor for the LatLng, have a look at the  [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng).

```
 map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-34, 151));
```

Split your pos variable and then use each Lat and Long in the constructor as follows.

```
var pos_array = pos.split(",");
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(pos_array[0], pos_array[1]);
```